# How can I call method from onPress on Alert function [React-Native]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

### How can I call method from onPress on Alert function [React-Native]

```
<Button
  onPress={{() => Alert.alert(
    'Alert Title',
    'alertMessage',
    [
      {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed!')},
      {text: 'OK', onPress: () => {this.onDeleteBTN}},

    ],
    { cancelable: false }
  )}}
  >
      <Text> Delete Record </Text>
</Button>
```

---

After OK button on Alert Dialog 
I need to call

```
onDeleteBTN = () => {
    alert(' OnDelete');
}
```

---

```
{text: 'OK', onPress: () => {this.onDeleteBTN.bind(this)}},
{text: 'OK', onPress: () => {this.onDeleteBTN}},
```

---

**It's not work**

---

Answer (score 26):

First issue, the `Button` component has a `title` prop instead of having `<Text>` as a child. Second issue is that you have a bunch of syntax errors and are not calling functions (or binding) correctly. If you fix that, then it should work fine; for example:

```
alert = (msg) => {
  console.log(msg)
}

onDeleteBTN = () => {
  this.alert(' OnDelete')
}

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        title="Delete Record"
        onPress={() => Alert.alert(
          'Alert Title',
          'alertMessage',
          [
            {text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed!')},
            {text: 'OK', onPress: this.onDeleteBTN},
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

*Note:*

- I don't know what your `alert()` function is supposed to do, so I made a dummy one that logs to console.
- There are other ways of doing this like calling `onDeleteBTN()` or binding.

Comment: Many Thanks . for this method :)

Comment: How can I pass a parameter to the function "onDeleteBTN" ?